# How to set a global variable value in C to shell environment variable?

Tags: u-boot

While porting U-Boot on a specific hardware,
a function has to parse a header to get OS entry point to jump into it.

Say, the function get's the os entry point into a global 'C' variable `uint32_t osentry`.

How to set this value to U-Boot shell command `'go'`?

I see U-Boot go (shell) command, has to be set as `go $entry` 
In few examples, I see the entry is fixed address set as shell environment value.

Whereas, for me it is in a global 'C' variable.

Comment: U-Boot supplies several commands to start OS kernels (bootefi, booti, bootm, bootz). The concept of all of these is that the kernel image supplies the entry point. U-Boot can read the file with the OS kernel from lots of different storage media. I can not think of any reason to hard code an entry point. - If you want to port U-Boot to a new hardware you should do it in a way that is compatible with upstream U-Boot and send patches to the developer list to get your hardware mainlined.

Comment: @Xypron, thanks,it is NOT hard-coded. The question is once the U-Boot gets the entry point, how it jumps into it. I see same sample boards use 'go' command to jump into the entry point. To follow that, I had to set the entry address in a environmental variable as 'go' is a shell command. If not, other way how U-Boot can jump into the entry point would be helpful.

Comment: Kernel images already contain a field indicating the entry point. You just load the kernel, the initial ramdisk and the device tree into memory and call the appropriate command to start the kernel passing the loading addresses.

Answer (score 1):

> How to set a global variable value in C to shell environment variable?

Use the **env_set_addr()** function to set an environment variable for use as an address from an ordinary program variable.
From **include/common.h**:

```
/**
 * env_set_addr - Set an environment variable to an address in hex
 *
 * @varname:    Environment variable to set
 * @addr:   Value to set it to
 * @return 0 if ok, 1 on error
 */
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

> For some reason, I could n't find this function in the code base I use.

You neglect to mention what version of U-Boot that you are using.
**env_set()** and its friends were apparently introduced in version 2017.09 to replace **setenv()** and its friends.

> I used similar setenv(), after formatting with sprintf.

Since version 2011.12 the simple **setenv()** has been augmented with **setenv_addr()** and/or **setenv_hex()**, which will convert the unsigned long integer to a string of hex digits for you.
If you are still using a version of U-Boot older than 2011.12, then you will have to do what you describe.

Comment: For some reason, I could n't find this function in the code base I use. I used similar setenv(), after formatting with sprintf. It can be done only after environmental settings are inited in the init sequence.